# Android App Offline Sync to Azure SQL Server and Blob Storage

Tags: android, sql-server, sqlite, azure, synchronization

I've created an Android App which the user creates data in an SQLite database and also creates picture and audio files. The next stage is to create an offline sync to Microsoft Azure (SQL Server and Blob Storage). There will be multiple devices for the App which all need to sync, so data on all devices will be the same.

What is the best method that encapsulates Android App SQLite to Microsoft SQL Server and created files to blob storage in Azure which will handle two way sync?

I've looked at Azure's MobileServiceClient but don't think that totally fits my needs as its just data tables. Maybe Sync Adapter instead?

I'm thinking I should create my own sync but not sure where to start? I think in the app i want to keep a changes table so when data is created or changed its logged in the table and then when it syncs it looks at this table and transfers the data and files. Then on the server side I'm not sure how to handle syncs from multiple devices so that all devices have the same data.

Anyway any pointers would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar SO thread [Upload images to Azure Blob Storage from an Android device With Offline Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742786/upload-images-to-azure-blob-storage-from-an-android-device-with-offline-sync) which discussed about offline sync for files with Azure Storage, that may helpful for you, but now Azure Mobile SDK for Android in Java doesn't support it, just implement the feature by self. If using Xamarin for Android, there is a solution introduced in the offical [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/sync-files-between-devices-azure-file-sync/), that you can refer to and possibly implement this in Java.

Hope it helps.